# How can I make shadows darker in unity5 without changing light intensity?

Tags: unity, lighting, shadows

I have a problem where I want the shadow cast by an object to be a well defined and dark one. However I have to do it without changing how illuminated the object looks so only increasing the intensity of the light won't do(I have already maximized shadow strength).

Is this something i can manipulate in engine or will I have to make some sort of shader adjustments?

This one has the correct illumination on the character:

[image: This one has the correct illumination on the character]

This one has the correct shadow color on the shadow cast by the character but it is to strongly illuminated:

[image: This one has the correct shadow color on the shadow cast by the character but it is to strongly illuminated]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the albedo (lightening the diffuse texture) of your background elements to increase contrast in shadowed areas? I assume you've already darkened your ambient light term or skybox lighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a spot light with increased `Range` and `Spot Angle`. Use full shadow `Strength`.

[image: spot light setup]

Comment: This is spot on :) Nice and simply, have a +1 !!

Comment: Thank you! that helped a lot, i used your suggestion combined with a "cast shadow only" mesh in the shape of the character head and it look great :) +1

Answer (score 0):

In unity 5.6, Windows->Lighting->Settings, turn environmental lighting down to your desired setting, this globally affects ambient light, but not direct lights.